# Merge sort for string getting null pointer exception?

Tags: java, mergesort

```
void MERGE(String[]A, int p, int q, int r)  {
    int n1 = q - p + 2;
    int n2 = r - q + 1;

    String[] L = new String[n1];
    String[] R = new String[n2];

    int i,j;

    for (i = 0; i < L.length; i++) {
        L[i] = A[p+i];
    }
    for (j = 0; i < R.length; j++) {
        R[j] = A[q+j+1];
    }

    L[n1-1] = "";
    R[n2-1] = "";

    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    for (int k = p; k <= r; k++) {
        if (L[i].compareToIgnoreCase(R[j]) < 0) {
            A[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else {
            A[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
}
public void MERGE_SORT(String[] A, int p, int r) {

    if (p < r) {
        int q = (p+r)/2;

        MERGE_SORT(A, p, q);
        MERGE_SORT(A, q+1, r);
        MERGE(A, p, q, r);
    }

}
```

This algorithm was originally for integers this how I changed it to sort strings. I get a NullPointerException. The problem seems to be at the compareToIgnoreCase() line. is this even how you implement mergesort for strings?
 [image: Console output]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] sA = {"Jack", "John", "Mike", "Moss", "Xo"};       
    Sort ob = new Sort();
    ob.MERGE_SORT(sA, 0, sA.length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second for-loop in method `MERGE` uses the wrong variable `i` (instead of `j`) for checking the upper bound (`i < R.length`). It should be:

```
for (j = 0; j < R.length; j++) {
    R[j] = A[q+j+1];
}
```

Apart from that, there are two other issues in the code:

(1) The for-loops for initializing L and R should run to `L.length - 1` respectively `R.length - 1`:

```
for (i = 0; i < L.length - 1; i++) {
    L[i] = A[p + i];
}
for (j = 0; j < R.length - 1; j++) {
    R[j] = A[q + j + 1];
}
```

(2) You are using a sentinel in L and R at the last place to guarantee that the merging for-loop never exceeds the arrays. This sentinel should be larger than the largest possible value in the array. In case of an `int[]` this could be `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (which is just as large as the largest possible element, but this might be acceptable). But as you have arrays of `String`, you'd need the largest possible `String` value. You are using the empty String (`""`) instead, which is the smallest possible `String`:

```
L[n1 - 1] = "";
R[n2 - 1] = "";
```

For testing, you can use something like `"ZZZ"`, but you should rewrite the merging algorithm to work without sentinel:

```
L[n1 - 1] = "ZZZ";
R[n2 - 1] = "ZZZ";
```

Comment: It took care of that but now I'm getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Yes, there are more issues in the code. You should better have a look at http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsMergesort/article.html#mergesort_overview to see a working example of merge sort.

Comment: @TheJuggler are you sure it works in all cases? An `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` usually has nothing to do with the type of array.

Comment: [link](http://www.codeshare.io/oPCl8 ) this works for integers with no problems as far as I can tell.

Comment: You're right. It works for integers. But it differs from your String-version (not only because of the data type). See my additions.